Achieving parallel wires with 180-degree rod rotations in an interconnected node system
We have 5 nodes on the left and 5 nodes on the right. You can imagine it this way: the nodes are on parallel rods and are connected with wires so that initially the wires are all parallel. We'll call this the initial state of the system. There are two directions of rotation for each rod, and the rotation is done by 180 degrees. After a single rotation, the wires become intertwined and stop being parallel.
A single transformation is a rotation of either rod in either direction.
A number of simple transformations is applied on the system.
The problem is this: bring the system to the initial state using a series of simple transformations if it is possible.
The source of this problem is that I stumbled upon an identical situation in real life and it looked like something that could be solved with maths so it got me curious.
I haven't tried anything yet because I'm not sure how to model this mathematically and I don't really know if there are analogous existing problems or what exact field this problem is related to.

Could you draw a picture? It sounds like this could have to do with recognising elements of the braid group and expressing them using generators.

@NaïmFavier https://imgur.com/a/WooN9O8 here's a simple drawing. Unfortunately I can't draw in more detail how the wires get intertwined exactly as I'd likely make mistakes, but it does seem to me that what I'm describing is really a 5-braid and the problem is to untangle the braid.

Edit: actually it's not a problem about untangling braids as in the usual definition. e.g. single simple transformation on the initial state of the system creates a knot that can't be untangled. So, the problem is to bring the system using a series of simple transformations to a state where the knot can be untangled.

You should describe your problem more precisely: what's the input, what's the output?

@NaïmFavier the input is a 5-braid. The problem is to untangle the braid by rotating the rods. So, by calling the actions of rotating either rod in either direction with "simple transformations", where a simple transformation is characterized by the rod(1/2) and direction of rotation (180°/-180°), the problem is to find a sequence of simple transformations (if such a sequence exists) that when applied one after another the braid would either be untangled or brought to a state where it can be untangled. That sequence would be the output

As a simple example imagine guitar strings attached to two parallel sticks on both ends. The only possible action is to rotate any of those sticks in either 180° or -180° (perpendicular to the viewer). After a number of rotations the result is a 5-braid. The problem is to reverse the process by finding the exact sequence of rotations and bring it back to the initial state. This sequence would be the output.

If the input is a sequence of rotations of the rods, then you can just output the sequence reversed and with each rotation reversed, so the problem is trivial. This is why you need to be precise about how things are represented. (Also, if you're just rotating the entire rod to which the strings are attached, then these are a very particular kind of braids which you can describe using $\mathbb{Z}$ instead of the whole braid group.)

@NaïmFavier yes but what if the initial sequence of rotations is not known? that's the problem. The input is just the current state/the braid. I should have formulated it in this way: someone applies a sequence of rotations and we don't know the sequence. The problem is to find that sequence. Just as today I had two big rods and 5 wires tangled in this way and I needed to untangle them (ended up just removing and reattaching the wires).

I guess there are two stages here, as a braid that is equivalent to the identity (your starting point) might still look quite complicated. In terms of equivalence, we have the following:
If we turn the top rod 180 clockwise, and then the bottom rod 180 clockwise, the turn of the bottom rod will undo the twists created by the top rod.
So we can assume that a 180 turn of the bottom rod is equivalent to minus a 180 turn of the top rod, and we just need to consider turns of the top rod. We'll need to shake the whole thing a bit or tug the rods tight to make sure that any string crossings that can be "cancelled out" actually are cancelled out.
There are only two things we can do: turn it clockwise, or turn it anti-clockwise. So the problem reduces to determining how many turns are needed (with a minus solution indicating that the turns should be anti-clockwise).
But to untangle it, we don't even need to know how many: all we really need to know is whether to turn the rod clockwise, or anti-clockwise, and then we can just keep doing it until the wires are untangled...
If we look at the braid generated, we'll see that turning the rod clockwise always adds left-over-right crossings, while turning it anti-clockwise adds right-over-left crossings (or subtracts left-over-right crossings that are already there). So we just need to look at the final braid. Give the end rods a tug to straighten out any crossings that have been "cancelled out". Then see if the crossings that remain are right-over-left or left-over-right, and start turning accordingly.
In practical terms, your problem may lie in the equivalence stages: "give the end rods a tug to straighten out...": we know that the braid you have is equivalent to a braid with either all right-over-left crossings or all left-over-right crossings, i.e. can be tugged/shaken into a braid of this form without any turns of the rod at all. But if it's very tangled and the strings/wires don't straighten easily, it might be hard to see it. Similarly at the end of the process even when the braid is equivalent to an identity braid, it might not immediately be obvious, so you might risk turning too far.
However, given the simple operation you have available (turning the rod), if you were to write down the braid in terms of Artin generators (crossings of two strings: we write $\sigma_i$ for string $i$ crossing over string $i+1$, and $\sigma_i^{-1}$ for string $i+1$ crossing over string $i$), you would be able to see the equivalences immediately: turning a rod in one direction corresponds to $\sigma_4 \sigma_3 \sigma_2 \sigma_1 \sigma_4 \sigma_3 \sigma_2 \sigma_4 \sigma_3 \sigma_4$ and in the other direction $\sigma_4^{-1} \sigma_3^{-1} \sigma_4^{-1} \sigma_2^{-1} \sigma_3^{-1} \sigma_4^{-1} \sigma_1^{-1} \sigma_2^{-1} \sigma_3^{-1} \sigma_4^{-1}$; if you put these two operations next to each other $\sigma_4 \sigma_3 \sigma_2 \sigma_1 \sigma_4 \sigma_3 \sigma_2 \sigma_4 \sigma_3 \sigma_4 \sigma_4^{-1} \sigma_3^{-1} \sigma_4^{-1} \sigma_2^{-1} \sigma_3^{-1} \sigma_4^{-1} \sigma_1^{-1} \sigma_2^{-1} \sigma_3^{-1} \sigma_4^{-1}$ the cancellations are fairly obvious...
(In fact, once you've performed these cancellations on the start braid, it's also easy to see how many turns you'll need).
